Как получить токен авторизации?
Пишу расширение и мне нужно из заголовка authorization получить токен. Вызываю событие так:
 chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(details => {
    console.log(details)    
}, {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}, ['requestHeaders', 'extraHeaders']);

В ответ получаю огромный объект где есть:

Данный токен с начальными символами схож что я вижу в запросах, но дальше этот токен вообще другой и по нему я не могу отправить запрос. Как получить верный токен? host_persmissions я передал
Также пробовал webRequest.onHeadersReceived тут вообще нет никакого токена с заголовками авторизации

Не совсем понятна последовательность ваших действий, и уж тем более подход к реализации. Весь ли процесс целиком в Service Worker? Но давайте поговорим о токене. То, что его начальная часть  одинакова, а отличается финальная? Вполне возможно, что эта "начальная часть" — своеобразная "соль", а остальная часть генерируется как ей и положено при каждом новом запросе. Попробуйте сделать несколько запросов подряд и проследите за этим.

А теперь главный эксперимент — попробуйте реализовать fetch (или что у вас там) прямо из chrome.webRequest из того места где у вас сейчас console.log() воспользовавшись полученными данными details. Почти на 100% уверен, что всё отработает как надо.
